# Bind onkeydown after TinyMCE is already initiated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce

I like to bind the event onKeyDown after tinyMCE has already initiated for the site.

`$('#content_ifr').keydown(...);` doesn't work here. So how could it be done?

Comment: jQuery selector is invalid... show HTML. Also where are you calling your keydown? Show more code

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your jQuery selector is invalid...it is looking for a tagName `content_ifr` which certainly can't exist. 
Assuming element has ID `content_ifr` use:

```
$('#content_ifr').keydown(...);
```

To call this after TinyMCE initialized use the TinyMCS `oninit` calback in your config object.

Reference docs:  http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:oninit

You can probably use jQuery event delegation to call your code any time without needing to call it in TinyMCE config using jQuery `on()` or `delegate()` methods

**EDIT:**  If element is an Iframe which I suspect it is from the selector, you would need to use `contents()` method to bind `keydown` event within the iframe

http://api.jquery.com/on/

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: Thanks. That's right it was invalid - wrote to quick. I am writing a plugin for wordpress and therefor can't hack into the init callback. Unfortunately I need to fetch the keydown or content change in some other way.

Comment: use delegation methods then, they can be called for future elements too. Not really clear what overall issue is

Comment: added extra info if element is Iframe

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#'+your_editor_id + '_ifr').bind('keydown',function(){
    //do what you like here with the event
});
```

Comment: `keydown()` is simply a shortcut for `bind('keydown...` so switching that doesn't bring anything new to the issue. http://api.jquery.com/keydown/   You will also generate an invalid selector with code shown

Comment: why will i generate an invalid selector?

Answer (score -2):

You can write something like this:

```
$('content_ifr').bind('keydown',function(){
    //your code goes here
 });
```

Comment: WHat's the difference??  Read docs for `keydown()` it is simply shortcut for `bind('keydown'...`   http://api.jquery.com/keydown/

Comment: this will only work if the html source element has id "content"!